# how to MYSQL compare values from same columns and join table

Tags: mysql, sql

how do i compare 2 table in mysql?
with the following table

name table ok1

```
   id model name
   1  AAA   AAA
   2  BBB   BBB
   3  CCC   CCC
```

name table ok2

```
   idok nameok
   1    ok1
   2    ok2
   3    ok3
```

and I want to generate a query

```
  id name model nameok idmodel namemodel modelmodel okname
  1  AAA  AAA   ok1    2      BBB       BBB         ok2
  1  AAA  AAA   ok1    3      CCC       CCC         ok3
  2  BBB  BBB   ok2    1      AAA       AAA         ok1
  2  BBB  BBB   ok2    3      CCC       CCC         ok3
  3  CCC  CCC   ok3    1      AAA       AAA         ok1
  3  CCC  CCC   ok3    2      BBB       BBB         ok2
```

the following sql I made, the query does not match what I want
sql query :

```
SELECT
t1.id,
t1.name,
t1.model,
t3.nameok as nameok1,
t2.id AS idmodel,
t2.name AS namemodel,
t2.model AS modelmodel,
t3.nameok as nameok2
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
ON t1.name <> t2.name AND
   t1.model <> t2.model;
inner join yourTable t1
 ON
   t1.id = t3.idok and
t2.id = t3.idok
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: thnks @Strawberry

Answer (score 2):

You can use `join`s:

```
select ok1.*, ok1_2.*, ok2.*  -- or whatever columns you want
from ok1 join
     ok1 ok1_2
     on ok1.id <> ok1_2.id join
     ok2
     on ok2.id = ok1_2.id;
```

Comment: I can't even try it @Gordon